# Windows boot problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed Boot Repair and now I boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 from the GRUB. However, the problem I have been facing is that my Windows frequently hangs during boot and I can never shut down properly whenever that happens. As a result, when I subsequently boot to Ubuntu I cannot access the files on the various partitions other than those on the Ubuntu ext4 partition. I once performed "Automatic Repair" on Windows 8 (after a Windows boot failure and restart) and consequently the GRUB ceased to be the default boot loader. Hence I had to boot to Ubuntu manually and run Boot Repair again. I wonder what has been going wrong. Does disabling Secure Boot cause these problems? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 acts differently than previous Windows when you shut it down.

[Here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/) is a good article about the Hybrid boot and shutdown.  The big picture is a restart is the only way to do a traditional full shutdown without using DOS or scripts.  If Windows doesn't put itself in a state where it's partition can be accessed (for example in hibernate you shouldn't be able to access it) then Ubuntu will not be able to mount the Drive.  So you have to find out why it's hanging on this hybrid boot or shutdown.

Also I've found with Windows 8, and haven't found the answer to this, that when you change files on the NTFS partition with Ubuntu, Windows often does not detect it and thinks there are file system errors.  I can make a test file in a folder on NTFS, and Windows 8 won't detect it.  Even worse, if I change a file or move files, Windows detects errors.  I have come to the point where I won't do any write operations on my NTFS partition.  I created a Shared EXFAT partition that both operating systems use to share files.  Sad that I had to use that (and still Windows won't see Linux created files on that).  Last time Windows "repaired" my drive because Ubuntu wrote files to it, Windows set all my folder permissions to Administrator and it couldn't load user settings.